# Extract Company names from Experience Section LinkedIn extract python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I need to extract the experience section and I need to scrape companies where he has worked(either previous or current) with python, I have tried but it is not working.

my code -

```
div = driver.find_element('div', class_='t-14 t-normal')
span = div.find_element('span', {'aria-hidden': 'true'})
text = span.get_text()
print(text)
```

Inspect element looks like -

this is just for a single company, btw all the inspect looks same for rest of the companies I checked.

[image: image_for_inspect_element]

```
<span class="t-14 t-normal">
    <span aria-hidden="true">
      <!---->
      "Financial Times . Full-time"
      <!---->
     </span>
```

link - https://www.linkedin.com/in/fred-thompson-8a892a19b/

So I just want to extract all the companies which are there in the inspect element. I am unable to do, it seems tough to apply a logic which will loop through all companies and get the names.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing Selenium syntax with `BeautifulSoup` syntax.
If you want to do this with Selenium your syntax should be as following:

```py
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".t-14.t-normal span[aria-hidden='true']")
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

However this will not work perfect since locators you are using here will match irrelevant elements too.

Comment: thanks @Prophet, but it doesn't prints the company name, rather it prints all the details, I only need company names only, please help

Comment: So, you want only the companies names - both current and previous or just previous?

Comment: yes only company names where he his working and previous companies also, basically all the companies in experience section

Comment: And I want to run for other profiles also, so it should work for any profile

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to find unique locators for that. I'm sorry

Comment: What does unique locators mean?

Comment: So its not possible with python anyway?

Comment: I guess - yes, but it will be more complicated way, not directly with a single locator

Comment: Could you please help, I need to do this task, its really urgent, I am not getting a way, I beg you please @Prophet

Comment: I understand. Currently I can't. Maybe later, but I can't promise.

Comment: okok, btw thanks, at least you give replies everytime